# Spring batch read csv and put data in memory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. I want to read a CSV file into Object on startup and put the object into `HashMap`. I see a sample example which shows read data from file and insert into database by using `JdbcBatchItemWriter`. Is there any built in class which helps me to put data in `HashMap` (in-memory). Does `ItemWriter<T>` will work. I wanted to use that `HashMap` through out my application.

Comment: Don't use Spring Batch for that. Just read the file and put it in memory, that is not what Sprnig Batch is meant to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @M. Deinum wrote in comment, Spring Batch is more for reading from one external source and writing to another external destination. But it can also be used for your implementation. Just  be aware of the general limitation: the whole data from the input file must fit in memory.

For reading from CSV file you have a ready-to-go FlatFileItemReader class.

Answering your question - there is one built-in class which can help you implement the writer. Check KeyValueItemWriter<K,V>. It is an abstract class, you will need to extend it for storing in a HashMap<K,V>.